# Interpreting WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE from IAudioClient::GetMixFormat

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, wasapi

I'm learning about Windows Core Audio APIs.  Using this [Rendering a Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316756(v=vs.85).aspx) example, I'm finding that [IAudioClient::GetMixFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370872(v=vs.85).aspx) returns an ambiguous [WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757714(v=vs.85).aspx) that looks like this:

```
Format
  wFormatTag          = WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE (65534)
  nChannels           = 2
  nSamplesPerSec      = 48000
  nAvgBytesPerSec     = 384000
  nBlockAlign         = 8
  wBitsPerSample      = 32
  cbSize              = 22
Samples  // this is a union
  wValidBitsPerSample = 32
  wSamplesPerBlock    = 32
  wReserved           = 32
```

Since `Format.cbSize` is 22, this is the entire structure; there is no `SubFormat` GUID to provide more information about the samples.  That seems weird because the format tag is `WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE`, which--I thought--means that you have to rely on the `Subformat` GUID to determine the actual format.

I can see that there are two channels of 32-bit samples.  How can I determine whether those samples are integers or floating point values?

[The [core-audio](/questions/tagged/core-audio) tag is apparently for an Apple API.  Is there a different tag for Windows Core Audio?]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

22 is the size of additional data that follows the [`WAVEFORMATEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757713) data:

> cbSize
>
> **Size, in bytes, of extra format information appended to the end of the `WAVEFORMATEX` structure**. This information can be used by non-PCM formats to store extra attributes for the `wFormatTag`. If no extra information is required by the `wFormatTag`, this member must be set to 0. For `WAVE_FORMAT_PCM` formats (and only `WAVE_FORMAT_PCM` formats), this member is ignored. **When this structure is included in a `WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE` structure, this value must be at least 22**.

If you look at the definition of [`WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757714.aspx), it begins with a `WAVEFORMATEX` and then contains extra data after it:

```
typedef struct {
  WAVEFORMATEX Format;
  union {
    WORD wValidBitsPerSample;
    WORD wSamplesPerBlock;
    WORD wReserved;
  } Samples;
  DWORD        dwChannelMask;
  GUID         SubFormat;
} WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE, *PWAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE;
```

That is a minimum of 22 bytes after the `WAVEFORMATEX` data.

The `SubFormat` field contains the format value you are looking for.

Comment: D'oh!  Thanks for the clarification.